# How to fix for loop skipping behavior

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
var lines = array.new_line()

entry = ta.crossover(ta.rsi(close, 5), 30) and array.size(lines) < 3
if entry
    array.push(lines, line.new(bar_index, close, bar_index, close))

exit = ta.crossunder(ta.rsi(close, 5), 90)
for [i, line] in lines
    line.set_xy2(line, bar_index, close)

    if exit
        array.remove(lines, i)
```

The code above supposedly creates a line from when `entry` condition is met up to when `exit` condition is reached. However, this is not the case, for some reason sometimes it "skips" an `exit` condition goes to the next one instead. How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deleting an element from the array, the remaining elements will shift their index, but the index `i` in a `for...in` loop will not until it completes all iterations.

Using the nested `while` allows you to remove lines one by one, since after each removal next line will replace the line with the same index `i`.

```
bgcolor(exit ? color.yellow : na)
for [i, line] in lines
    if exit[1]
        while array.size(lines) > 0
            array.remove(lines, i)
    else
        line.set_xy2(line, bar_index, close)
```

[image]

Comment: Learned something new today! Thank you.